# How to output the first date field from a record

Tags: output, record, datefield

Here is a sample record from a data file

```
Ram|2015-03-01|204012|||inact|2014-02-01|
```

There are hundreds of such records. I want to retrieve the first date field from the first record. I tried using grep but it prints the entire line.

Output should be:

```
2015-03-01
```

Comment: What was the grep command you used?

Comment: hi i used this command..
head -1 filename|grep "[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}"
and i got the entire line.. like i said i want only the first occurence of a date filed in the first record.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the --only-matching option in the [Grep Man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep). You'll have to rewrite your regex to match the first two fields, then use grep again to get the date field. E.g. `grep --only-matching [regex for first two fields] | grep --only-matching [regex for date field]`.

Comment: I'm not going to write the solution for you. I can at best help you fix your problem. But to do that You've to tell me how to reproduce the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-asky